# $\phi$ is a homeomorphism of $(X, \tau)$ onto a dense subspace of $(X^{**}, \theta)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

> $X, Y$ are the Banach spaces. Let $\phi$ be the embedding of $X$ into $X^{**}$. Let $\tau$ be the weak topology of $X$, let $\theta$ be the weak*-topology of $X^{**}$ - the one induced by $X^{*}$. Prove that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism of $(X, \tau)$ onto a dense subspace of $(X^{**}, \theta)$

Hi everybody. I'm doing this exercise in Rudin book, but can't find any clue to solve this. Even I can't specify what is the neighborhood for an element in $\theta$. Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Density of the image of $\phi$ follows from [Goldstine's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem). We have to show then that $\phi\colon X\to \phi(X)$ is a homeomorphism. It is clear that $\phi$ is injective. Let $(x_\alpha)$ be a net in $X$ convergent to some $x\in X$ weakly. This means that $\langle x_\alpha-x, f\rangle \to 0$ for each $f\in X^*$. Now,

$\langle f, \phi(x_\alpha-x)\rangle = \langle x_\alpha-x, f\rangle \to 0$

so $\phi$ is $\tau$-to-$\theta$ continuous. You can reverse this argument to show that $\phi^{-1}$ is $\theta$-to-$\tau$ continuous.